# How to create a FormType without any entity?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I just created a new form in `AppBundle/Form/Type` named `ContactType.php`

It's just a form with a field email and message, to send an email.

How can I instantiate this form in my controller (I don't have any entites linked with) ? I tried somethings like :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
```

But symfony wants a string for argument of `createForm()`... Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified class name of your form type class like this (you may have to adapt the `use` statement to your needs):

```
use AppBundle\Form\Type\ContactType;

$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
```

Using the `class` constant requires you to use PHP 5.5 or higher. If you still use PHP 5.3 or 5.4, you will need to use the FQCN as a string:

```
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\Type\ContactType');
```